# Is "and" the exact same as "&&" in Mathematica?

Tags: boolean-computation

Does the word "and" compile the exact same way as "&&" or are there differences?

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please post code that has led you to ask this question. Also evalute: `a && b // FullForm` to see if this answers your question. Thanks.

Comment: An expression like `And[...]` is already in standard form. So, when the code is parsed, there is no change to that expression and evaluation follows in the expected manner. An expression like `...&&...` is a special form that must first be parsed into standard form. This requires considering operator precedence. Standard form is unambiguous with regard to the order in which expressions are evaluated, but infix form generally is not. So, the difference isn't with compilation (whatever you meant by that), but with what happens before "compilation".

Answer (score 7):

`and` has no special meaning in Mathematica but `And` has - it is a logical AND. The following four forms are equivalent.

```
(And[a, b, c]) === (a && b && c) === (a ∧ b ∧ c) === (a \[And] b \[And] c)

(* True *)
```

There is also bitwise AND defined by `BitAnd` in Mathematica, in case you was looking for such an AND.